# Unable to handle notification pop up using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to 'allow' or 'block' the notification alert that gets poped up after loading the facebook homepage. Iam trying to do this using robot framework.Below is the I have written so far.

```
 *** Settings ***
 Library  SeleniumLibrary


 *** Variables ***

 *** Test Cases ***
 Login to Facebook
 open browser  https://facebook.com  Chrome
 maximize browser window
 input text  id=email  abc@gmail.com
 input text  id=pass  test123
 click button  xpath=//input[@data-testid="royal_login_button"]
 sleep  15
 #   switch browser  get alert message
 handle alert 

 select from list by value  xpath=//*[@id="userNavigationLabel"]  Log Out
```

Can anyone please help me to get rid of the notification pop up and continue with execution.

Answer (score 3):

In order to disable this feature in Chrome we pass the ***--disable-notifications*** flag.

To do this we need to create the Chrome Options object from selenium and pass it through to ***Create Webdriver*** method. This results in an additional step calling ***Go To*** which navigates to the required page.

I was able to login to Facebook with the following code and no notification appears:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Login to Facebook
    ${options}=    Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver.chrome.options'].Options()    sys
    Call Method     ${options}    add_argument    --disable-notifications
    ${driver}=    Create Webdriver    Chrome    options=${options}
    Go To     https://facebook.com
    maximize browser window
    input text    id=email    abc@gmail.com
    input text    id=pass    test123
    click button    xpath=//input[@data-testid="royal_login_button"]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response,but Iam kind of new to this. After adding the code given by you, its throwing below error.Could you please help.Login to Facebook                                                     | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
${options}=                                                           | FAIL |
Variable '${options}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @ShruthiPrasad are you sure you have the correct spacing in your robot file? Usually see this error when things are not indented correctly or spaced correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was spacing problem. Its working perfectly fine now. :)